# "Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a page where I try to submit a form:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { useSignIn } from '../../hooks/Auth/useSignIn';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function SignIn() {
    const { mutateAsync, error, isError, isLoading } = useSignIn();
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleSubmit = async (event: Event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(event.target);
        const email = data.get('email')!;
        const password = data.get('password')!;

        await mutateAsync({ email, password });
        history.push('/dashboard');
    };

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='py-3'>
            <Form.Group controlId='email'>
                <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type='email' name='email' />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId='password'>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type='password' name='password' />
            </Form.Group>
            ...
        </Form>
    );
}

export default SignIn;
```

However, every time I try to test my code, the `onSubmit` part of my Form throws me the following error:

```
Type '(event: Event) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': cancelBubble, composed, returnValue, srcElement, and 7 more.ts(2322)
```

How can I solve this error? My theory is that I have to define my `handleSubmit` function as a `FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>` type, but I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: You have different types with the same name coming from different places. Use intellisense to figure out which `Event` you should be using. IIRC there is a generic `Event` and a separate one exported from `react`. But then maybe `react-bootstrap/Form` uses a different one.

Comment: Worst case, `react-bootstrap/Form` uses and older version of `@types/react` or similar that is causing a conflict.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631847/types-of-parameters-event-and-event-are-incompatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct type is `event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>`

A good tip for finding the proper type is to create a form, use an arrow function, and let the VSCode autocomplete the proper type.

[image]

Comment: The correct type is whatever `react-bootstrap/Form` uses. Since that's the component he is using.